# How to reflect store's sorters on grid view?

Tags: extjs4, store, extjs

After dozens of answers in the ExtJS/Sencha category, here is my first question for all you ExtJS experts -:)

In my `Ext.application.launch`, I am doing something like this -

```
Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('store_id').sorters.add(new Ext.util.Sorter({
            property : 'field name',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }));
```

After this, when I load the store, the sort info is passed to the server as expected. (Its a Direct Store)
No problems here.

The problem is -
I have a grid that is backed by this store and this "sort info" is not reflected on the grid view the way it is reflected if I manually sort on a column in the grid. (i.e. I don't see the sort icons on the corresponding column)

Is there way to decorate the grid columns with appropriate sort icons based on store's sorters?

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: can you post the code for your grid?

Comment: @Jaitsu its nothing fancy. simplest of the grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never :)
Instead of filtering the store itself, do

```
{grid column}.setSortState('ASC', true, false);
```